# access and modify iTunes library from another application

Tags: ios, itunes, itunes-sdk

I was wondering if there is any way that I could access my iTunes data (info of the songs) and modify the data (create new (smart) playlist, add songs to a playlist, add comments to a song) from another iOS application?

I'm basically thinking about creating an app that can sort and organize my songs automatically in a custom way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how in c#:

```
    // initialize Itunes connection
    iTunesApp itunes = new iTunesLib.iTunesApp();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // get main library playlist
         ITLibraryPlaylist mainLibrary = itunes.LibraryPlaylist;
         // Gets a list of all playlists and adds them to the combo box
         foreach (ITPlaylist pl in itunes.LibrarySource.Playlists)
         {
               comboBox1.Items.Add(pl.Name);
         }
         // Gets the tracks within the mainlibrary
         GetTracks((ITPlaylist)mainLibrary);
         // Sets the datagridview1 data source to the data table.
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;
    }
```

It would be helpful to know what iOS application or programming language you were wanting to use.